# What is the 'this' keyword in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

What is the specification of the 'this' keyword in Solidity?
How does it work?

Sample code from [Solidity Features · ethereum/wiki Wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features)

```
contract Helper {
  function getBalance() returns (uint bal) {
    return this.balance; // balance is "inherited" from the address type
  }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to [this guide](https://ethereumbuilders.gitbooks.io/guide/content/en/solidity_features.html):

> Contracts Inherit all Members from Address.

It means that `this` is the pointer to the current instance of the type derived from Address (in your case - current instance of Helper), and `balance` is a member of Address.

It helps you distinguish between contract's own balance and any other balance, like in this [example](https://ethereumbuilders.gitbooks.io/guide/content/en/solidity_tutorials.html):

```
address payable x = 0xFFfFfFffFFfffFFfFFfFFFFFffFFFffffFfFFFfF;
if (address(x).balance < address(this).balance) 
    address(x).transfer(10);
```

And here is a some kind of definition (from [this doc](http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#index-4)):

> **this**: the current contract, explicitly convertible to address

Comment: why is `this` necessary? Can't someone just say `if(x.balance < balance)`?

Comment: this (current contract’s type):
    the current contract, explicitly convertible to Address.

This is from the solidity docs. Which means that if you want to access members of the address type (e.g. balance) of the current contract instance, then you can simply use `this`. In your example, `balance` will try to access a variable from the contract's storage (i.e. contract public property)

Comment: `this.balance` is deprecated, the correct way to get the balance of the contracts is through `address(this).balance`

Comment: does simply writing `this;` in a contract do anything?

Answer (score 6):

Contract types are implicitly convertible to address and every contract inherits all members of "address" and overwrites them if necessary.
If they are overwritten, the members of address can still be accessed via conversion to address:

```
address(myContract).send(10).
```

This also has the effect that all members of address can be accessed without prefix, i.e. `uint x = this.balance`; // access the balance parameter of the current contract.

so to summarize "`This`" represents the current contract instance.

Comment: sometimes I see in ERC20 contracts `balanceOf(this)`

Comment: `balanceOf(this)` is just a function to get the balance of `ERC20` token for the currrent contract, however `address(this).balance` is the balance of Ether for a current contract.

Answer (score 3):

These answers are good but they're not correct.

```
pragma solidity 4.24;
contract my contract {
function example() public view returns (address) {
      return this;
}
}
```

What do you get? You get an address. The address of the contract.

It is NOT a state dependent variable or a use case of scope like in javascript, where you can use this to pull the global state into a callback.

It is NOT just an address, it can be viewed as a class variable which gives access to everything the contract has access to, think of it like a key but honestly I only use it to reference to it's own address.

For future reference, wrap it as such,

```
address(this)
```

To properly utilize.